# Replacing empty values in dataframe with column name with respect to row rank

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following set up for my problem. I have a dataframe, `GEO`,

```
{'index': {0: 2,
  1: 3,
  2: 25,
  3: 26,
  4: 27,
  5: 28,
  6: 32,
  7: 33,
  8: 78,
  9: 83,
  10: 91,
  11: 96,
  12: 98,
  13: 99,
  14: 138,
  15: 155,
  16: 156,
  17: 1790},
 'id': {0: 'A001DS007',
  1: 'A001DS01',
  2: 'A001GS10',
  3: 'A001GS11',
  4: 'A001GS12',
  5: 'A001GS13',
  6: 'A001GS17',
  7: 'A001GS18',
  8: 'A003DS05',
  9: 'A003DS10',
  10: 'A003GS02',
  11: 'A003GS07',
  12: 'A003GS09',
  13: 'A003GS10',
  14: 'A005DS03',
  15: 'A005GS01',
  16: 'A005GS02',
  17: 'R13C1G'},
 'geometry_zone': {0: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602b9d3fa0>,
  1: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602b9d3af0>,
  2: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026d9cee0>,
  3: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026d9cc40>,
  4: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026d9c940>,
  5: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1601dd8e1f0>,
  6: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602b9f86a0>,
  7: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602b9f8e20>,
  8: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026dae790>,
  9: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026dae1f0>,
  10: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16023fd80d0>,
  11: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026279d00>,
  12: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x160262797c0>,
  13: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026279880>,
  14: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x16026da3820>,
  15: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602be25f70>,
  16: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602be3dd60>,
  17: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1602bafdbb0>},
 'centroid': {0: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029e24e80>,
  1: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029e24c10>,
  2: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x160299e6220>,
  3: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x160299e6850>,
  4: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029befe50>,
  5: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029befdf0>,
  6: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029bef1f0>,
  7: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16029befd90>,
  8: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bce6160>,
  9: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bcc3790>,
  10: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bcc3640>,
  11: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bcc36a0>,
  12: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bcc3730>,
  13: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602bcc3670>,
  14: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x16025cc3af0>,
  15: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602b9f8100>,
  16: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1602b9f8d30>,
  17: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1601e48eb50>},
 'A001DS007': {0: 1,
  1: 10,
  2: 8,
  3: 8,
  4: 7,
  5: 6,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 6,
  9: 5,
  10: 12,
  11: 2,
  12: 5,
  13: 5,
  14: 10,
  15: 10,
  16: 10,
  17: 13},
 'A001DS01': {0: 13,
  1: 1,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 4,
  6: 13,
  7: 13,
  8: 10,
  9: 14,
  10: 2,
  11: 14,
  12: 14,
  13: 14,
  14: 7,
  15: 7,
  16: 8,
  17: 3},
 'A001GS10': {0: 14,
  1: 2,
  2: 1,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 14,
  7: 14,
  8: 18,
  9: 17,
  10: 7,
  11: 16,
  12: 16,
  13: 16,
  14: 11,
  15: 11,
  16: 16,
  17: 6},
 'A001GS11': {0: 12,
  1: 3,
  2: 2,
  3: 1,
  4: 3,
  5: 3,
  6: 11,
  7: 11,
  8: 16,
  9: 15,
  10: 5,
  11: 12,
  12: 13,
  13: 13,
  14: 12,
  15: 12,
  16: 12,
  17: 8},
 'A001GS12': {0: 9,
  1: 5,
  2: 4,
  3: 2,
  4: 1,
  5: 2,
  6: 8,
  7: 9,
  8: 14,
  9: 12,
  10: 6,
  11: 11,
  12: 10,
  13: 10,
  14: 13,
  15: 13,
  16: 11,
  17: 9},
 'A001GS13': {0: 7,
  1: 7,
  2: 5,
  3: 5,
  4: 2,
  5: 1,
  6: 7,
  7: 7,
  8: 11,
  9: 10,
  10: 8,
  11: 9,
  12: 9,
  13: 9,
  14: 14,
  15: 14,
  16: 14,
  17: 11},
 'A001GS17': {0: 3,
  1: 13,
  2: 11,
  3: 10,
  4: 10,
  5: 8,
  6: 1,
  7: 2,
  8: 15,
  9: 8,
  10: 14,
  11: 6,
  12: 7,
  13: 7,
  14: 17,
  15: 17,
  16: 17,
  17: 15},
 'A001GS18': {0: 4,
  1: 14,
  2: 12,
  3: 12,
  4: 12,
  5: 10,
  6: 2,
  7: 1,
  8: 17,
  9: 7,
  10: 16,
  11: 8,
  12: 6,
  13: 6,
  14: 18,
  15: 18,
  16: 18,
  17: 16},
 'A003DS05': {0: 8,
  1: 8,
  2: 10,
  3: 11,
  4: 11,
  5: 12,
  6: 10,
  7: 10,
  8: 1,
  9: 6,
  10: 4,
  11: 4,
  12: 8,
  13: 8,
  14: 6,
  15: 6,
  16: 5,
  17: 10},
 'A003DS10': {0: 10,
  1: 18,
  2: 18,
  3: 17,
  4: 17,
  5: 16,
  6: 9,
  7: 8,
  8: 9,
  9: 1,
  10: 18,
  11: 7,
  12: 3,
  13: 3,
  14: 15,
  15: 15,
  16: 13,
  17: 18},
 'A003GS02': {0: 11,
  1: 4,
  2: 7,
  3: 6,
  4: 6,
  5: 7,
  6: 12,
  7: 12,
  8: 4,
  9: 11,
  10: 1,
  11: 10,
  12: 11,
  13: 11,
  14: 5,
  15: 5,
  16: 6,
  17: 2},
 'A003GS07': {0: 2,
  1: 9,
  2: 9,
  3: 9,
  4: 9,
  5: 9,
  6: 4,
  7: 6,
  8: 2,
  9: 4,
  10: 11,
  11: 1,
  12: 4,
  13: 4,
  14: 8,
  15: 8,
  16: 7,
  17: 12},
 'A003GS09': {0: 5,
  1: 15,
  2: 15,
  3: 13,
  4: 13,
  5: 13,
  6: 5,
  7: 4,
  8: 5,
  9: 3,
  10: 15,
  11: 3,
  12: 1,
  13: 2,
  14: 9,
  15: 9,
  16: 9,
  17: 14},
 'A003GS10': {0: 6,
  1: 17,
  2: 16,
  3: 16,
  4: 14,
  5: 14,
  6: 6,
  7: 5,
  8: 8,
  9: 2,
  10: 17,
  11: 5,
  12: 2,
  13: 1,
  14: 16,
  15: 16,
  16: 15,
  17: 17},
 'A005DS03': {0: 18,
  1: 16,
  2: 17,
  3: 18,
  4: 18,
  5: 18,
  6: 18,
  7: 18,
  8: 12,
  9: 16,
  10: 13,
  11: 18,
  12: 18,
  13: 18,
  14: 1,
  15: 3,
  16: 3,
  17: 7},
 'A005GS01': {0: 17,
  1: 11,
  2: 13,
  3: 15,
  4: 16,
  5: 17,
  6: 17,
  7: 17,
  8: 7,
  9: 13,
  10: 10,
  11: 15,
  12: 15,
  13: 15,
  14: 2,
  15: 1,
  16: 2,
  17: 4},
 'A005GS02': {0: 15,
  1: 12,
  2: 14,
  3: 14,
  4: 15,
  5: 15,
  6: 16,
  7: 15,
  8: 3,
  9: 9,
  10: 9,
  11: 13,
  12: 12,
  13: 12,
  14: 3,
  15: 2,
  16: 1,
  17: 5},
 'R13C1G': {0: 16,
  1: 6,
  2: 6,
  3: 7,
  4: 8,
  5: 11,
  6: 15,
  7: 16,
  8: 13,
  9: 18,
  10: 3,
  11: 17,
  12: 17,
  13: 17,
  14: 4,
  15: 4,
  16: 4,
  17: 1}}
```

where the column names are the same as the `id` and the values in each row is an indicator of how close to the `id` the item in the column name is (It ranks all the calculated distances).

```
GEO =
index         id                                      geometry_zone  \
0      2  A001DS007  POLYGON ((53.16200 50.20131, 52.84363 48.45026...   
1      3   A001DS01  POLYGON ((59.04953 49.34561, 58.77158 47.52346...   
2     25   A001GS10  POLYGON ((58.72525 45.79395, 59.72898 45.57777...   

                    centroid  A001DS007  A001DS01  A001GS10  A001GS11  \
0  POINT (53.49869 49.22928)          1        13        14        12   
1  POINT (59.29040 48.38586)         10         1         2         3   
2  POINT (59.35477 46.54529)          8         3         1         2   

   A001GS12  A001GS13  A001GS17  A001GS18  A003DS05  A003DS10  A003GS02  \
0         9         7         3         4         8        10        11   
1         5         7        13        14         8        18         4   
2         4         5        11        12        10        18         7   

   A003GS07  A003GS09  A003GS10  A005DS03  A005GS01  A005GS02  R13C1G  
0         2         5         6        18        17        15      16  
1         9        15        17        16        11        12       6  
2         9        15        16        17        13        14       6
```

At the same time, I have this other dataframe,

```
item = {'Code': {0: 'A1',
  1: 'A2',
  2: 'A3',
  3: 'A4',
  4: 'A5',
  5: 'A6',
  6: 'A7',
  7: 'A8',
  8: 'A9',
  9: 'A10',
  10: 'A11',
  11: 'A12',
  12: 'A13',
  13: 'A14',
  14: 'A15',
  15: 'A16',
  16: 'A17',
  17: 'A18',
  18: 'A19',
  19: 'A20',
  20: 'A21',
  21: 'A22',
  22: 'A23',
  23: 'A24',
  24: 'A25',
  25: 'A26'},
 'Manual': {0: 'A003GS07',
  1: 'A003GS07',
  2: 'A003GS07',
  3: 'A003GS02',
  4: 'A001GS10',
  5: 'A001GS11',
  6: 'A001GS18',
  7: 'A001GS12',
  8: 'R13C1G',
  9: 'A001GS12',
  10: 'A001GS18',
  11: 'A001GS17',
  12: 'A001GS13',
  13: 'A001GS13',
  14: 'A003DS10',
  15: 'A005GS02',
  16: 'A003DS05',
  17: 'A005GS01',
  18: 'A003GS09',
  19: 'A003GS10',
  20: 'A003GS10',
  21: 'A003GS10',
  22: 'A003GS10',
  23: 'A003GS10',
  24: 'A003GS10',
  25: 'A005DS03'},
 'closest_1': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: ''},
 'closest_2': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: ''},
 'closest_3': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: ''},
 'closest_4': {0: '',
  1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: ''}}
```

```
 Code    Manual closest_1 closest_2 closest_3 closest_4
0    A1  A003GS07                                        
1    A2  A003GS07                                        
2    A3  A003GS07                                        
3    A4  A003GS02                                        
4    A5  A001GS10                                        
5    A6  A001GS11                                        
6    A7  A001GS18                                        
7    A8  A001GS12                                        
8    A9    R13C1G                                        
9   A10  A001GS12                                        
10  A11  A001GS18                                        
11  A12  A001GS17                                        
12  A13  A001GS13                                        
13  A14  A001GS13                                        
14  A15  A003DS10                                        
15  A16  A005GS02                                        
16  A17  A003DS05                                        
17  A18  A005GS01                                        
18  A19  A003GS09                                        
19  A20  A003GS10                                        
20  A21  A003GS10                                        
21  A22  A003GS10                                        
22  A23  A003GS10                                        
23  A24  A003GS10                                        
24  A25  A003GS10                                        
25  A26  A005DS03
```

Now, I want to replace all the empty columns with the four closest items, by row, so the first row would be

```
 Code    Manual closest_1 closest_2 closest_3 closest_4
0    A1  A003GS07 A001DS007 A003GS07 A001GS17 A001GS18
```

which are the column names corresponding to the ranks 1,2,3,4 in the first row.

I've tried merging, joining, creating dictionaries for each row and then dropping any element larger than 4 in that dictionary...but none of the attempts are close to working.

If anyone has an idea on how to achieve this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your example is too complex and not reproducible because of `<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x160299e6850>`

Comment: Could you edit you question to make it more accessible? It is a bit hard to use the data, especially since you have objects than cannot be translated by just copy/pasting. Also the description of what you want to achieve not very clear. Nevertheless, I think I figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call the first DataFrame `df1`, and the second `df2`.
You can compile first a DataFrame with the 4 closest points for each row, and then use it to replace the values in `df2`. I used absolute positions to identify the columns starting in "A00…" but you could also use a filter on the names, depending on your use case.

```
subs = (df1.set_index('id')
           .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.iloc[2:]
                                       .sort_values()
                                       .iloc[:4]
                                       .index),
                  axis=1))
df2[['closest_1', 'closest_2', 'closest_3', 'closest_4']] = df2['Manual'].apply(lambda x: subs.loc[x])
```

output:

```
   Code    Manual closest_1  closest_2  closest_3 closest_4
0    A1  A003GS07  A003GS07  A001DS007   A003GS09  A003DS05
1    A2  A003GS07  A003GS07  A001DS007   A003GS09  A003DS05
2    A3  A003GS07  A003GS07  A001DS007   A003GS09  A003DS05
3    A4  A003GS02  A003GS02   A001DS01     R13C1G  A003DS05
4    A5  A001GS10  A001GS10   A001GS11   A001DS01  A001GS12
5    A6  A001GS11  A001GS11   A001GS12   A001GS10  A001DS01
6    A7  A001GS18  A001GS18   A001GS17  A001DS007  A003GS09
…
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!